# I need help animating UICollectionView cell size when collection view size changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that takes up the entire screen, and inside it are cells that are the same exact size as the collection view.  When the user hits a button, the collection view animates to take up only half the screen (and another view is shown beside it).  This is fine, but the cells themselves are still the size of the original collection view.

I can call `invalidateLayout` on the collection view's layout, and this will cause `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to be called and the cells are all recalcualted, and the sizes are changes, but these do not animate, they simply snap to the new size.

Is there a way to animate these cell size changes at the same time, or in the same animation block that animates the size change to the parent collection view?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

    for (int i =0; i<count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    }

} completion:nil];
```